# {CSS} A different color for the line which is drawn on a text by "text-decoration: line-through"?

Tags: css, line-through

Is it possible to change color of the line on wrapped text? I mean, e.g, a black text and a red line!?

[image]

Comment: I added the correct answer ;-) i'm sorry for misread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do some CSS tricks to do it like this:

```css
    .line-through-text {
        position: relative;
        color: blue;
    }

    .line-through-text:before {
        border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<h2>
Hello There! <span class="line-through-text">This is wrong,</span> This is correct
</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, i'll post correct  answer in a minute :) (misread)

```js
var pOut = $("span").css("text-decoration"); //line-through
if (pOut == "line-through") {
  $("span").css("color", "red");
}
```

```css
span {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>hello <span>crazy world</span> world!</p>
```

Edit:

```css
span {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
span.redline:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 55%;
  left: 0;
  border-top: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 4px solid;
}
```

```html
<p>hello <span class="redline">crazy</span> world!</p>
```